# why my fixed top navbar keep moving around 20px when i scroll to end page with (device mode google inspect element)

Tags: css, html, css-position, navbar

why my fixed top navbar keep moving around 20px when i scroll to end page with (device mode google inspect element only)

(THE PROBLEM ONLY COME WHEN I SCROLL THE PAGE TO THE BOTTOM END)
when i try use jsfiddle or manually reduce browser size everything fine

somehow when you erase the text, the problem is gone

[image]

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
    padding-top: 0px;

      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse"> 
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
       

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-fixed-top" data-recalc="false" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#offcanvas" data-canvas="body">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
            
      

    </div>
    

  






<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 

            <!-- if you erase this the problem gone -->
                 <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="span4 collapse-group">
                        <h1>Collection 2</h1>
                        <h2>Spring Summer 2015</h2>
                       <h3><p class="collapse text-center">Deskripsi collection diisi disini askldmalksd alksdmalk sakldmalk daklsmdla askdmal skamdalms askmdla kasmldaml aksmdlmdksa aksmda askmda aksdam aksdmaks askdmals askdmal askdmald aksdmakl asdkmalkdsa kasmdlamd aksdmkl askdmalksmdkamdka aksdmalmdskamd askdmalkmsdlad kamsldam</p></h3>
                      <p><a class="btn" href="#">Read More ▽</a></p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            <!-- end of the problem -->



 
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

i have been try to change erase "p" and add the "p" class to "h3" but the problem still same

does that's bug from google inspect element device mode?

really appreciate with your help and your time sir

Comment: margin-bottom: 20px on navbar ?

Comment: @fadomire see the question sir, the problem only show when i scroll and reach end of the page :) thanks for the down vote tho

Comment: the problem is not clear enough. Is the problem the 20px blank part when you scroll down ? if yes, just add a css style like .navbar {margin-bottom: 0} to counter bootstrap default style

Comment: @fadomire i put some pic so you will understand

Comment: a link to your implementation / site could be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

There is an unnecessary ">" symbol after your `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">` div. Please remove that.

Also at the end of the document there three ending of div's with no start point. Remove them as well.

And remove `p` from inside of `h3`. This is not valid.

Comment: Please remove all the junk codes from your codes & try. Hope that will solve the issue. And if you can make a working sample of your issue, that will help.

Comment: i dont even see junk code, please tell me which one is junk if there is some. and there, with pic sample, i use the same code..

don't you see i remove that already before but that fiddle and nothing happen, i told that in my question

Comment: Those three ending `</div>` at the end are of no use, as they do not have any starting `<div>`. Remove them, and test in an actual device. Also, a `p` element inside of a `h3` element is not valid HTML and is a bad practice. Always try to write valid HTML.